# problem calling a function in php mysqli

Tags: php, oop

the following is the class i tried to develop in oo way in php but as a begginer in php oo i am getting and error message which i do not know how to solve. please point out the fault thanks.

```
class MySQLi_DB  extends mysqli {
    private static $_instance = null;


    private function __construct($db="test",$host="localhost", $user="root", $pass="") 
    {

        parent::__construct($host, $user, $pass, $db);
        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
                    . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    static public function getDB()
    {
        if(self::$_instance == null)
        {
            self::$_instance = new MySQLi_DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;

    }

    public function select($sql)
    {
        $res =  $this->query($sql);
        return $res->fetch_all();


    }
}
```

i instantiate the object as below

```
require_once 'MySQLi_DB.php';
        $db = MySQLi_DB::getDB();
       $data =  $db->select("select * from cms");
```

and the error is below

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   mysqli_result::fetch_all() in
>   D:\wamp\www\Driver\MySQLi_DB.php on
>   line 39

Comment: MySQLi_Result function fetch_all() and $this->query() return MySQLi_Result http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) mysqli_result::fetch_all() is only available when the MySQL native driver is installed. Please ensure that it is installed and enabled for you configuration.

Comment: oh thanks i think that could be the reason so how can i confirm i mean through which cfg variable i check if mysqlnd is installed ?

Comment: I wasn't able to determine the name of the cfg variable, but if you search the output of phpinfo() for 'mysqlnd' you should be able to verify whether it is installed. The documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/) will help with installation and configuration.